# Pass element to multiple function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm working on a program that shuffles cards in a deck and returns a picture of the card when the user hits the "deal" button. But I am trying to pass `fileName` from the `deal` function to the `refreshImages` function and I can't seem to get it to work. Wondering if someone can show me how and explain why. Thanks.

```
def deal(self):
    card = self.deck.deal()
    self.stateLabel["text"] = str(card)
    fileName = "DECK/" + str(card.rank) + card.suit[0] + ".gif"
    self.refreshImages(fileName)
    if len(self.deck) == 0:
        self.dealBtn["state"] = "disabled"

def shuffle(self):
    card = self.deck.shuffle()
    fileName = "DECK/" + str(card.rank) + card.suit[0] + "gif"
    self.refreshImages(fileName)
    if len(seld.deck) == 0:
        self.dealBtn["state"] = "disabled"

def refreshImages(self):
    """Updates the images in the window."""
    self.image = PhotoImage(file = fileName)
    self.cardLabel1["image"] = self.image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `deal` method calls the `refreshImages` method with a file name as an argument, the `refreshImages` method should be declared with such a parameter; otherwise the caller's local variable `fileName` won't get magically passed to the method being called:

```
def refreshImages(self, fileName):
    """Updates the images in the window."""
    self.image = PhotoImage(file = fileName)
    self.cardLabel1["image"] = self.image
```

Comment: I did this in the beginning, but I guess I mistyped fileName... I'm an idiot. Thanks a lot though.